# iso installed debian 8.2.0, but boot fails with strange textscreen artifact with red character

Tags: debian, system-installation, nvidia, startup, debian-installer

I got it to install on dev/sdb from DVD. (debian-8.2.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso)
Basic install, default desktop. No extra packages from DVD#2#3 or via package manager installed.

During startup, the textscreen suddenly goes half-the-brightness(or another screen mode), and after some seconds, on top of the text screen, a blank line and a red square character appears?!
I couldn't find any errors in the /var/log/
[(Foto's and video here)](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/l9qvpqafhrngzqs/AABgvvQOC_bZdixxcocQFlFEa?dl=0)

(jfyi: I installed GRUB on /dev/sdb, and instructed bios to boot from the Seagate drive. (The Maxtor /dev/sda had sectors relocated, so decided not to use it). Also the graphical linux environment 'partedmagic' from Hirens BootCD 14 works fine)

---

note: i got a reply on reddit forum:

> ECPilot - I had some similar issues with the DVD install...but, no issues at all
>   using the "net install" .iso. --- good luck.

But i really like the dvd install to work.
I hope someone knows where to start. i'm fairly new to this. thx

Comment: strange indeed. It might have nothing to do with it, I would run a memtest just to be sure of having all my RAM ok.

Comment: Did the one which comes with HirensBootCD14. it didn't find memory issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  Something with the graphics was wrong.

i disabled the 'nouveau' NVIDIA driver by following [this GRUB2 instruction](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=79797#p435313)
And although i did see the weird blank line and red dot while starting, then it did continue into a graphic environment! :)
Then i could install the latest NVIDIA drivers, using
https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#Debian_8_.22Jessie.22